# JQuery (Bookmarklet) - Add a selection from another list select

Tags: jquery, select, bookmarklet, fieldset

I use a webpage which has 2 lists. The first list is the complete list of available items to choose from and the 2nd list is the chosen items list. Every time I have to add a certain item from the available items to my chosen list so I want to use JQuery and save a bookmarklet to get rid of repetetive selections and saves.

Example:

```
<fieldset>
<center>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-5">
<select name="b_main[]" id="search" style="background:#f2f2f2;" size="20" multiple="multiple">
<option value="84">A1</option><option value="61">A2</option><option value="60">A3</option> </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<select name="b[]" id="search_to" style="background:#f2f2f2;" size="8" multiple="multiple">
<option value="58">B1</option><option value="50">B2</option><option value="38">B3</option>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</fieldset>
```

b_main[] is the available items list. I want to add A1 to my chosen list b[].

GOAL: I want A1 to be removed from b_main[] and added to b[] and save the code as a bookmarklet.

Comment: I have used getElementsByName and getElementsById before with JQuery and could set them a value but this operation is adding an option from a list to another list, so I'm lost here ...

Comment: So what's the goal you're aiming for here? Click on A1 in `b_main[]`, and it adds A1 to `b[]`?

Comment: yes, I want A1 to be removed from b_main[] and added to b[]

Comment: This does the job but I want to save it as a bookmarklet. How can I save this code as a bookmarklet for only A1 (value=84)?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by saving it "for only A1" - if you want to run it as a bookmarklet, copy/paste the JavaScript from codepen into a minifier (e.g. https://javascript-minifier.com) and add that as a bookmark.

Comment: for example I use this bookmarklet that I coded myself to select an item from a list and then submit the data:
javascript:document.getElementsByName('location')[0].value = 49;document.getElementsByName('servers[]')[0].value = 49;$("input[value=approve]").click();$('form').submit();

so I want sth like this but this seems more complicated to me ...

Comment: I've updated my post with a bookmarklet version - how's that?

Comment: This works, but I have to click on A1 after I click on the bookmarklet. Where should I add the value of A1 in the code, so the change is done automatically by clicking on the bookmark. Not by on function and selecting the Value A1.

Comment: Should I use 84 instead of SelectedVal?

Comment: Ah ok, if you just wanted the first value then the selector could be `#search [value="84"]` - I've updated my post again.

Comment: Yep, great. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrMGVz

Here's the JavaScript with comments:

```
// Column we're selecting from
var columnA = $("#search");

// Column we're moving values to
var columnB = $("#search_to");

// Move value A1 to column B
columnA.find('[value="84"]').detach().appendTo(columnB);
```

and as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function() {$(function() {var columnA = $("#search"); var columnB = $("#search_to"); columnA.find('[value="84"]').detach().appendTo(columnB); }) })()
```